# Discord.py | Slash commands aren’t working

Tags: discord.py

I’m trying to have my discord bot (using discord.py) support slash commands like this picture shown.
[image]

I already have installed `discord-py-slash-command`, put the code to import it `from discord-py-slash-command import SlashCommands` and invited my bot using the `application.commands`. I have this code shown. (I’m trying to add the slash to the ping command)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import Commands
from discord-py-slash-command import SlashCommands

client = commands.Bot(commands_prefix=“.”)

@client.commands(description=“Ping”)
async def ping(ctx):
     await ctx.send(“Pong!”)

client.run(“MY_TOKEN”)
```

I also tried `@client.commands.slash`

I’m new to this slash thing. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Quickstart](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) page has example code on how to create slash commands.

```py
import discord
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True) # Declares slash commands through the client.

guild_ids = [1234567890] # Put your server IDs in this array.

@slash.slash(name="ping", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def _ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

client.run("token")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but why do I need to have a guild id? Is the underscore on _ping necessary?

Comment: I have little experience with the library, but my guess is that the `guild_id` is needed to register the slash command to the guild. You can try removing all references to it to see if it still works. For calling the coroutine `_ping`, you can probably remove it without any problems.

Comment: Okay thanks. I tried doing it without guild_id and it worked most of the time but some of the time it just errors.

Comment: The need to pass the guild ids seems to have been fixed in `discord-py-interactions ~= 3.0.2`

@Justin For future reference, the underscore is not necessary, and if you do not pass `name=` the slash command will have the same name as the function that handles it.