# Why is my slash command not displayed despite correct usage?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently working with the `discord-py-slash-command` library and have read through the documentation here: https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

But for whatever reason it doesn't work, the command is not recognized/on the two servers, and the private messages of the bot the slash command doesn't show up.

I know that `discord.py` doesn't support slash commands yet, but this lib actually seems to work, at least from what I saw. Does anyone here see the mistake I made? I followed tons of tutorials with no success...

I already removed `sync_commands=True` or even tried to remove `guild_ids` and then wrote a message to the bot. Global commands take up to an hour to be displayed, but I actually avoid that with `guild_ids`.

**Here is my code so far:**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand # The lib

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

TOKEN = "..."

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")
    print(slash.commands)
  # Prints: {'ping': <discord_slash.model.BaseCommandObject object at 0x000002184B23E708>}
guild_ids = [812510632360149XXX, 871078836870185XXX]

# Directly from the docs!
@slash.slash(name="Ping", description="Ping command", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def _ping(ctx):  # Defines a new "context" (ctx) command called "ping."
    await ctx.send("Pong!")


@client.command(name="test") # Test command which works
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I also looked at other questions like: [Discord.py | Slash commands aren’t working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448865/discord-py-slash-commands-aren-t-working) but they did not help either. Is this a problem with how I code/the program? (PyCharm)

Comment: Did you select `applications.commands` while generating an invite link for the bot? If not you must select `applications.commands` and `bot` and generate an invite link in the OAuth2 section of the developer portal. Invite the bot again. Check the image for more clarification  [https://i.imgur.com/OoC6Kve.png]

Comment: @TaufeeqRiyaz Yes, I invited the bot with the correct settings (`bot` and `applications.commands`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to set it to "True" in the `App Settings` of Discord. Here we turn on `Text Box` and can now use Slash commands, Most of the time this will be the error, because your code itself does not contain any, at least from what I have tested.

**Here is a picture:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about `PRESENCE INTENT` and `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` in bot settings? cause i copied your code and tried to run, it worked for me. I've attached the images here.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctQKI.jpg

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand # The lib

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")



guild_ids = [85528118773940xxxxx]

@slash.slash(name="Ping", description="Ping command", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def _ping(ctx):  # Defines a new "context" (ctx) command called "ping."
    await ctx.send("Pong!")


@client.command(name="test") # Test command which works
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")


client.run('token')
```

Comment: The code would not even run if I disabled the intents in the Discord Developer Portal. I have actually checked everything, the intents are also on, that's why I asked the question here, because I can't explain it.